# Clarification for this exercise needed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I would like to solve the following exercise but there are a few minor things I am not clear about:

Let $A$ be the Banach algebra of $C^1([0,1])$ endowed with the norm $\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty$. Let $p:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ be the map $p(x) = x$. Show that $p$ generates $A$ as a Banach algebra.

Now, I believe *generates as a Banach algebra* means that the closure of the algebra generated by $p$ equals $A$.

Now question 1: When saying a function from a real interval into the complex numbers is differentiable, does it mean complex or real differentiable? I thought that it must mean complex differentiable. Is that so?

My next thought was that maybe the exercise is missing the unit. If the set was $\{1,p, \overline{p}\}$ then it would follow from the Stone Weierstrass theorem that this generates $C[0,1]$.

I guess if it is complex differentiable then it's analytic so can be expressed as a power series. Somehow that still needs a unit though. Or doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of the functions - $[0,1]$ - is real, so the differentiability is real differentiability.

Concerning the unit, the exercise presumes the generated algebra to be unital, so the Banach algebra generated by $p$ is the smallest closed subalgebra of $C^1([0,1])$ containing $1$ and $p$. (Otherwise, $p$ would not generate the full algebra.)

Note that $\overline{p} = p$ here, so the algebra generated by $p$ (or $1$ and $p$) is closed under conjugation. [You could also just look at only real-valued functions, it is an essentially real situation.]

The Stone-Weierstraß theorem deals with approximations in the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ norm, which is different from the norm used here, so you cannot quite directly use it. However, a small indirection employs the Stone-Weierstraß theorem to get the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you know that when the domain is real then differentiability is real, too? After all, the definition of the derivative involves a limit in the range. Oh, I see. Maybe when the domain is real there are only two directions from which to approach the point?

Comment: Just to be clear: by ''essentially real situation'' you mean that these functions do not take on any complex values at all?

Comment: Not quite. By "essentially real" I mean that the real and imaginary parts of the functions are not related as they would be by complex differentiability, so you can treat the approximation of real and imaginary parts separately. You get real coefficients for the real parts, and purely imaginary coefficients for the imaginary parts. Essentially, a complex-valued function of a real variable is a pair of real-valued functions.

Comment: Okay, I now understand why it is real differentiability. Thank you! What I'm still not sure about is the unit. Because on page 3 and 4 the book says ($A$ is an algebra here) ''Hence for any subset $S$ of $A$ there is a smallest subalgebra $B$ of $A$ containing $S$ ... If $S$ is the singleton $\{a\}$  then $B$ is the linear span of all powers $a^n$ ($n=1,2,...$) of $a$.'' Is this ''$n=1,...$''  a typo?

Comment: A typo or an inconsistency. If you don't include the unit in the generated algebra, then here $p$ does not generate the full algebra, but only the ideal $\{ f\in C^1 : f(0) = 0\}$. So unless they screwed up royally, in the exercise they assumed that the algebra is the (closure of) the span of $\{ p^n : n \geqslant 0\}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now regarding the exercise: I think I finally figured out the ''indirection''. Can you please tell me if this is what you had in mind?

Comment: From basic real analysis we have the following theorem: If $f_n$ is a sequence of differentiable functions such that $f_n'$ converges uniformly to some function $g$ on $[a,b]$ and if there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f_n(x_0)$ converges then $f_n$ converges uniformly to some $f$ and $f'=g$.

Comment: Applying this theorem and the Weierstrass approximation theorem: Let $f \in C^1$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. By Weierstrass there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n'$ such that $p_n' \to f'$ uniformly. Using the other theorem with $f_n (x) = \int_0^x p_n' (y) dy$ we get a function $g$ such that $f_n \to g$ uniformly. Then 
$$ g(x) = \lim_n \int_0^x p_n' (y) dy = \int \lim_n p_n' (y) dy = \int_0^x f' (y) dy = f(x)$$ Hence $p_n \to f$ uniformly. Now $p_n \to f$ in the $\|\cdot \|$ norm is a piece of cake.

Comment: You forgot to add $f(0)$, $f_n(x) = f(0)  + \int_0^x p_n'(y)\,dy$. Yes, that is precisely the indirection I meant. Uniformly approximate the derivative, and integrate.